# Identity server multi tenant (authenticate against multiple database)

Tags: c#, authentication, identityserver4, openid-connect, identityserver3

I am trying to set up an identity server, I have gone sample example on GitHub but none of them really helped me.

My Scenario:

I have multiple products, which has its own database. I want to configure a single (central) Identity server which should detect the source request and authenticate against the respective database (User table UserName and Password) and return to respective return URL of the application. Also, I have a plan to authenticate against third-party provider as well(clever, class link, etc).

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem than you. I use a tenantId in my Identity Table

Check out this

http://ericsmasal.com/2018/06/05/capture-tenant-in-asp-net-core-2-0-web-api/

Answer (score 0):

If you want Identity server to authenticate against a different database per tenant using the domain/url it’s accessed through then it's possible to do so using an open source project called saaskit.

https://github.com/saaskit/saaskit

https://benfoster.io/blog/saaskit-multi-tenancy-made-easy

Comment: I want to use IdentityServer.

Comment: Yep you add the saaskit nuget package to your identity server project and configure accordingly.